# Can I RedirectMatch w/ regex to redirect multiple individual pages with similar url patterns?

Tags: 301-redirect, regex

Goals is to use one RedirectMatch statement to redirect 50+ pages with slightly changing names.

**Examples:** `https://www.example.com/galler-prime-alpaca-heathers-mermaid.shtml`
`https://www.example.com/galler-prime-alpaca-heathers-autumn.shtml`
*etc*

**Redirect to:**
`https://www.example.com/fab-prime-alpaca-heathers-mermaid.shtml`
`https://www.example.com/fab-prime-alpaca-heathers-autumn.shtml`
*etc*

Comment: Just from galler-prine to fab-prime ?  Is that the only pattern ?

Comment: yes that is the only pattern thanks